# NSLayoutConstraint from TabView bar o Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I am messing around with constraints in Swift and have one real nagging problem I have is setting distances over navigation bar and tab bars.  Is there any way to set a constraint to make itself a certain distance from the top including the navigation header (or bottom including the tab bar) instead of the real (0,0) at the top leftmost corner of the screen?  Sample code below just to show you what I am dealing with.

let viewsDictionary = ["tableView": tableView, "changeDirectionButton": changeDirectionButton, "adBanner": appleAd]

```
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
self.view.addSubview(changeDirectionButton)
self.view.addSubview(appleAd)

let view_constraint_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "H:|-[changeDirectionButton(60)]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
let view_constaint_H2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "H:|[tableView]|",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
let view_constraint_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "V:|-70-[changeDirectionButton(60)]-[tableView][adBanner]-60-|", 
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

self.view.addConstraints(view_constraint_V)
self.view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H)
self.view.addConstraints(view_constaint_H2)
```

Comment: Try using content insets of table view.

Answer (score 0):

For the bottom and top I added:

```
super.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.Top & UIRectEdge.Bottom
```

which worked